# :inputText only gives null back?(setter are not reached)

Tags: java, netbeans, jsf-2, jsf-1.2

i am coding a register-form in jsf:

in the *.xhtml file:

```
   <h:outputLabel class="Float" for="password" value="Passwort"/>
   <h:inputText id="password" rendered="true" value="#{Register.password}" label="Passwort">
   <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="8"/>
  </h:inputText>
 </fieldset>
</h:form>
```

in the bean:

```
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String pwd) {
    this.password = pwd;
}
```

I set a breakpoint and noticed that my setter are not reached?

why?

**++++1.Update++++++**

Register.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;

@ManagedBean(name="Register")
@SessionScoped
public class Register implements Serializable{

    private String password = "Fill in!";

    /** Creates a new instance of Customer */
    public Register() {
        //null
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String pwd) {
        this.password = pwd;
    }
```

**++++2.Update++++++**

```
<div id="buttons">
   <h:commandButton id="enter" accesskey="r" value="Registrieren" action="#{Register.registerPlayer()}" immediate="true"/>
</div>
```

**++++3.Update++++++**
my form code:

```
<!-- Login-->


<h:form>
                        <h3><span xml:lang="en">Login</span> Daten </h3>
                        <div class="formblock">

                            <fieldset>
                                <div>
                                    <h:outputLabel class="Float" for="username" value="Username"/>
                                    <h:inputText id="username" rendered="true" value="#{Register.username}" label="Username">
                                    </h:inputText>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h:outputLabel class="Float" for="password" value="Passwort"/>
                                    <h:inputSecret id="password" rendered="true" value="#{Register.password}" label="Passwort">
                                    </h:inputSecret>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>

                        </div>
                        <div id="buttons">
                            <h:commandButton id="enter" accesskey="r" value="Registrieren" action="#{Register.registerPlayer()}" immediate="true"/>
                              <!-- <h:outputText value="#{msg.wrongpwd}" rendered="#{loginCtrl.loginfailed}" style="color: red"/>
                              <h:messages style="color: red"/> -->
                        </div>
                    </h:form>
```

Comment: Could you please show us the `Register` bean's code

Comment: what data you enter and submit the form ? I hope it validates the validation you specified

Comment: @JigarJoshi Yes, I think that's his problem too. Btw, bean naming convention is to start with lower-case letter. In your case the class name is `Register`. Without specifying the name, JSF automatically converts it to `register` with lower-case letter. So there is no need to specify it unless you want to have it different, like `registerBean`.

Comment: @user1248720 do you have comandButton ? to submit the values?

Comment: @Fallup OP has already specified bean name with annotation (apart from conventions, there is no issue with that)

Comment: @JigarJoshi Ofcourse, I know that he specified the bean name in annotation and I'm not saying there is any issue with that. Just wanted to clarify when he needs to do that + showing convention.

Comment: btw thx for all your answers!!! what do you mean by validation? h:inputText has a password, but its a string element so is that validation enough?

Comment: You have placed `<f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="8"/>` as an implicit validation. It means if you don't enter password between 3 to 8 chars the validation will fail and your setter wont get called. Try to enter 4 char password, if it is not working you are not submitting the form at all as @Daniel stated.

Comment: kk i deleted the validators and used one form element for all my inputText Elements. But i get as comment in netbeans:                                                             The attribute action is not defined in the component interface!!

Comment: There is nothing bad on using validation... Please post related xhtml code. Seems like you are missing the basics.

Comment: You are skipping the whole Apply Request Value phase - Update Model value phase with `immediate="true"`, so your values wont get updated. Remove that.

Comment: @user1248720 not sure how reliable the netbeans warning in this case , does the submiting works for you if you place all in one form?

Comment: the immediate="true" was the mistake!!! thx all to your answers!!! and thx Fallup!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you have `immediate="true"` on your `commandButton`. This seems like a probable cause why your model is not being updated.

[This blog entry](http://radio.javaranch.com/gthought/2005/01/04/1104874993000.html) seems to describe a similar, if not the same, problem. Now, there are some workarounds for this, either you can get the submitted value directly from the component by using the `bind` attribute, or you can use `immediate="true"` on the input components as well, but I think the best solution would be not to use `immediate` on your submit button unless you really need it.

Comment: I just scanned the comments and I missed that. Why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Because it was related to discussion in comments and I'm not sure if it is the main root of the problem. I would post it as answer after his confirmation of success :P, or maybe not, I don't care about reputation that much.

Answer (score 1):

Place your `h:commandButton` and the `<h:inputText` in the same form that you are trying to submit...